# Does python have font face for strings?

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I recently used Google Vision API to extract text from a pdf. Now I searching for a keyword in the response text (from API). When I compare the given string and found string, they do not match even they have same characters. 
The only reason I can see is font types of given and found string which looks different which lead to different ascii/utf-8 code of the characters in the string. (I never came across such a problem)

How to solve this? How can I bring these two string to same characters? I am using Jupyter notebook but I even pasted the comparison on terminal but still its evaluates it to False.

Here are the strings I am trying to match:

```
'КА Р5259' == 'KA P5259'
```

But they look the same on Stack Overflow so here's a screenshot:

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: These aren't different *fonts* they are different characters

Comment: It looks like it is using cyrillic instead of latin characters. Perhaps a language setting on the API?

Comment: Unicode doesn't have different characters for different typographic styles in general but does when the style affect the meaning or has a particular context like mathematics or language's writing system.

Comment: To be clear, the problem characters are U+41a, U+410, and U+420 -- Cyrillic capital letters Ka, A, and Er, respectively.

Comment: As per API for the given language it should return Latin characters. But is there anyway to convert it to normal case and perform string comparison?

Comment: @AMIT Just curious, what language is it?

Comment: @wjandrea  Its python and I was making a call to Vision API.

Comment: @AMIT I mean what language are you processing with the Vision API? Cause if it's Russian for example, then Cyrillic is to be expected.

Comment: @wjandrea Its German which has mainly Latin characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the your comments.

I found the solution. I am posting it here, it might be helpful for someone. Actually it's correct that python does not support font faces. So if one copies a font faced character and paste it to python console or jupyter notebook (which renders the font faces due to the fact that it uses html to display information) it is considered a different unicode character.

So the idea is to first bring the text response in a plain text format which I achieved by storing the response in a .txt file (or .pkl file more precisely) which I had to do anyway to preserve the response objects for later data analysis purposes. Once the response in stored in plain text file you can read it without any font face problem unlike I faced above.

Comment: Still not "font faced" characters. The OCR has simply recognized Cyrillic characters rather than latin. iconv transliteration is one option to reduce things to similar-looking ASCII (though it seems not these). Also, use `repr` to show actual values; in this case, `u'\u041a\u0410 \u0420'`.

Comment: I think you are right! API might have detected similar looking characters from other writing systems.